# Export to excel without using third party dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there anyway to export to excel using .Net framework 4.5 or above without using any third party dlls ?

Comment: xlsx files are just zipped collections of XML files, so as long as you roll your own zip file creator and write out the XML as specified by the OpenXML spec, yes.  But why make things difficult for yourself?

Comment: What do you mean by "excel"? Do you mean the XLSX file format or simply a way to get data into the application "Excel"? If the latter, just writing out a plain CSV file is the easiest approach in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ways of working with Office files:

**If you need only the new formats (.xlsx):** OpenXML SDK. Or the ZipArchieve and XML writer classes.

**Old and new Formats:** the (t)rusty office COM interop. While this does support both old and new formats, it has limitations. It needs office isntalled and requires a interactive session on top of all the normal COM interop issues. It is normally not suiteable for Webpages

**The OleDB data provider:** I was only informed of them my self recently. Apparently new ones even support the new office formats.

My personally adivce is to always use the OpenXML SDK.

Comment: Thank you , I think except OleDB approach all of the above method would require an external dll reference . Could you please provide me a code sample / reference how we can create and write into xlsx using Oledb. Many thanks in advance .

Comment: As i said: I have exactly 0 experience usign OlebDB for creating/modificaiton of XLSX files. This might be a decent place to start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971514.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code,

```
    public static void ExportToExcel(string fileName, string query)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
            {

                using (DataTable dt = GetData(cmd))
                {
                    GridView GridView2 = new GridView();
                    GridView2.AllowPaging = false;
                    GridView2.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView2.DataBind();

                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xls", fileName));
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "HEllo";
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

                    for (int i = 0; i <= GridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        //Apply text style to each Row
                        GridView2.Rows[i].Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
                    }

                    GridView2.RenderControl(hw);
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                }
            }
         }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WebMsgBox.Show(ex.Message + "Please try After sometime");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I dont have a grid .